# Haskell GUI programming tools

Tags: haskell

This might seems silly question but for me it is annoying.

I have installed Haskell platform in my PC using Portable option from the installation options as I do not have admin privileges. So the total Haskell files are now stored in D Drive and I am able to use this without any problems. But when I search for GUI programming in Haskell I have got many articles in Google and I came to final conclusion that I need another library or tool or plugin(*I dont know which is correct*) to make GUI programming possible in Haskell.
But here my questions are:

1. What are best tools for windows for GUI programming?
2. How to install the extra library or tool and attach it to 
        portable Haskell platform?

Comment: I think the main problem with GUI programming in Haskell on Windows is installing the underlying C/C++ libraries. I do neither GUIs nor Windows, however, so I might misremember.

Comment: Not really an answer, but if you don't have admin privileges I'd recommend you do stuff like this on a virtual Linux machine where you do. You can easily port the applications to Windows later if you've used e.g. gtk2hs for the GUI.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Installing Virtual machine is a very good option, But to install virtual machine again I need admin privileges :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Haskell wiki has a [comprehensive list](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/GUI_libraries) of available GUI libraries for Haskell.

The problem with GUI programming in Haskell is not so much the lack of available tools and libraries, but the fact that using Haskell to write GUI programs in the usual imperative event driven style doesn't take full advantage of the functional nature of Haskell.

There are a number of approaches aiming to address this problem, but, as far as I know, they are all pretty much at the "research" stage, meaning they are not yet quite as mature (both in theory and in practice) as the mainstream (non-functional) techniques. If you are interested in this direction, take a look at some of the functional reactive projects listed in that wiki page, as well as [reactive-banana](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana).

As for your second question (how to install Haskell libraries), you can use [cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/), which is included in the Haskell Platform. [This page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install) explains how to install packages with it.

Comment: The particular problem with GUI tools on Windows is to install the underlying C/C++ libraries. cabal-install is of little help there.