# Is there a way to get a Haskell setup on Windows without an installation? (Copy + paste)

Tags: windows, haskell, compiler-construction, ide

I am programming on a school-given computer. I need to have a Haskell setup that does no installation (one I can drop on a flash drive and copy on to the C drive or just use from the flash drive perhaps).

I already have Eclipse up and running, so if I could get it on Eclipse without leaving any impact on the system past the Eclipse directory, that would be very good as well.

By no installation, I mean I have to be able to easily remove the program and roughly all traces without any uninstaller tool. All uninstaller tools are likely blocked.

What are my options?

Comment: I think there is a standalone option during install http://www.haskell.org/platform/

Comment: The installer has a [portable option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641851/haskell-gui-programming-tools), at least according to that link... Hope that helps!

Comment: Another option is to use a [GHC bindist](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_1#binaries).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. These are satisfactory for an answer, so I will give the answer to whoever puts this up. I will do it myself tomorrow, but I don't deserve the stackoverflow-points. Hopefully this will serve as a reference to people asking the same thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/)'s Windows installer (of which I'm the maintainer) has a "portable install" option that just extracts the files to the given location and does not touch the registry or any system settings. You can use it to install Haskell Platform to your flash drive, but you'll need to add GHC's location to the PATH manually.

Comment: How does one add the path on a Windows machine?

Comment: So you would have to change the computers settings then?

Comment: How does one use portable install with GHCI 8.0.1? When I download it all I get is a .exe file. When run it doesn't offer a portable install option. Thanks.

Comment: I am also unable to run as admin, so chose the portable install option but for some reason the install is not showing up anywhere on my machine - the target is in program files, and the uninstall exe is placed into my app data/roaming/bin .... but no hackshell install anywhere else - any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I'm from the future. I'm using [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/)'s Windows installer as [Mikhail Glushenkov said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350161/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-haskell-setup-on-windows-without-an-installation-copy#14350419).

> So you would have to change the computers settings then? –  PyRulez

You can also set environment variables with `CMD.exe`'s `SET` command. (What're they teaching you kids these days?) Once you've set `PATH` (or whatever) like this the value will persist for that session and any child sessions. If you start an IDE from the shell - it should have those set (unless there's a previous instance ... maybe) so it should work within the constraints you gave. I'd recommend that you save it to a `.bat` file

**TL:DR**; extract the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/) create `shell.bat` next to `bin/` `lib/` et al and paste this into it;

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PATH=%~dp0/bin;%PATH%
CMD /K
```

Now run `shell.bat` and that prompt will be able to find Haskell. Since you can take `shell.bat` with you - it should be easier to plug-in to a new lab-machine and get working

Comment: No school like the old school :)