# New to haskell, cabal is not found

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal

I try to run `cabal` from `cmd` on Windows however it isn't recognized. I have modified my `PATH` variable to include the bin directory of my haskell install however that does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/)?

Comment: Yes. Installed as portable. It was like 1gb.

Comment: @meiryo Are ghc and ghci available?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350161/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-haskell-setup-on-windows-without-an-installation-copy/14350419#14350419

Comment: @Dave yes absolutely. I've gotten a hello world working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my Haskell Platform installation (I'm using 2012.4 on Windows), the `cabal.exe` executable is confusingly *not* under `<HASKELL_PLATFORM_DIR>\bin` (where `ghci.exe` and friends live) but under `<HASKELL_PLATFORM_DIR>\libs\extralibs\bin`.

You could try adding the latter directory to your path as well; that worked for me, at least.

Comment: Thanks. Everything runs smoothly!